# Automated Warning message appended to the email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I am testing the rails action mailer with my application to send emails to my mail Id. The mail is being delivered successfully to my inbox, but, the following Warning message is being automatically appended at the end of the email.

***WARNING : This message originates from the Internet***

Can anyone please guide me if any setting needs to be done in the action mailer to remove this message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using as an inbox?

Comment: My corporate email address